# How to use pickle to save data to disk?

Tags: python, pickle

I'm making a Animal guessing game and i finish the program but i want to add pickle so it save  questions to disk, so they won't go away when
the program exits. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 15):

Save an object containing the game state before the program exits:

`pickle.dump(game_state, open('gamestate.pickle', 'wb'))`

Load the object when the program is started:

`game_state = pickle.load(open('gamestate.pickle', 'rb'))`

In your case, game_state may be a list of questions.